# Render Image actor on top of TiledMap in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, actor, tile

I have created 10 object layers using Tile software,and rendering tiled map using OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer object.

```
                    renderer.setView(camera);
                    renderer.render();
```

I have created backgroundTiledMap class extending Actor class to it.
adding object of the backgroundTiledMap class in  stage of mainGame class. 
Its rendering perfectly.

but when I am trying to add next actor to the same stage. its not getting rendered.

is there any different way of using tiled map and actors to detect collision in between.

Below the actual code

`backgroundTiledMap.java` class which is extended as actor and used to draw background from tiled map (created in tile software)

```
                public class BackgroundTiledMap extends Actor {

                        public MapProperties properties;
                        public MapLayer layer;
                        public MapObject mapObject;
                        public TiledMapTileLayer tiledLayer;
                        private TiledMap map;
                        private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
                        private OrthographicCamera camera;
                        public Array<Rectangle> tiles = new Array<Rectangle>();

                        private Pool<Rectangle> rectPool = new Pool<Rectangle>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Rectangle newObject () {
                                return new Rectangle();
                            }
                        };

                        GameStartPoint game;
                        Stage  stage;
                        Reptile reptile;

                        public BackgroundTiledMap(GameStartPoint game,Stage stage)
                        {
                               this.game = game;
                               this.stage = stage;
                               init();

                        }


                        public void init()
                        {
                            map = new TmxMapLoader().load("Images/GuideCrocodile.tmx");
                            renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / 16f);

                            camera = new OrthographicCamera();
                            camera.setToOrtho(false, 70, 50);
                            camera.update();
                            stage.setCamera(camera);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
                            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
                            render();

                        }

                        public void render()
                        {
                            camera.update();
                            renderer.setView(camera);
                            renderer.render();

                        }




                    }
```

this is `mainGame` screen used to create stage and all other actors and objects are added here

```
                    public class GuideCrocodileScreen implements Screen {

                        public GameStartPoint game;
                        private Stage stage;

                        public BackgroundTiledMap backgroundTiledMap;
                        public Reptile reptile;
                        MoveToAction moveAction;

                        public GuideCrocodileScreen(GameStartPoint game)
                        {
                            this.game = game;
                            stage = new Stage();

                        }


                        @Override
                        public void render(float delta) {
                            // clear the screen
                            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f, 1);
                            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
                            stage.draw();
                        }


                        private void addReptile(){

                            reptile = new Reptile(stage,100,100,50,50);
                    //        backgroundTiledMap.getTiles(100,100,50,50);

                            reptile.addListener(new InputListener() {
                                public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                                    System.out.println("down");
                                    return true;
                                }

                                public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                                    System.out.println("up");
                                }
                                public void touchDragged (float x, float y, int pointer) {
                                    reptile.updateReptile(x,y);
                                }

                                public boolean touchMoved (float x, float y) {
                                    //reptile.updateReptile(x,y);
                                    return false;
                                }

                            });
                            stage.addActor(reptile);

                        }



                        @Override
                        public void resize(int width, int height) {

                        }


                        @Override
                        public void show() {

                            addBackgroundArea();
                            addReptile();
                        }




                        private void addBackgroundArea(){
                            backgroundTiledMap = new BackgroundTiledMap(game,stage);
                            stage.addActor(backgroundTiledMap);
                           }


                    }
```

new actor class , this is actor to move around the screen detecting collision with the objects drawn on   backgroundTiledMap  `reptile.java` (this is not getting rendered)

```
                    public class Reptile extends Actor  {

                        public GameStartPoint game;
                        private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
                        public SpriteBatch batch;
                        public int screenWidth;
                        public int screenHeight;
                        private Texture reptiletexture;
                        private TextureRegion reptileRegion;
                        private Stage stage;

                        public Reptile( Stage stage,int x, int y,int width, int height){



                                setX((float)x);
                                setY((float)y);
                                setWidth((float)width);
                                setHeight((float)height);
                                this.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
                                 this.stage = stage;
                                initialize();


                        }

                        private void initialize(){

                            this.screenWidth = GameStartPoint.WIDTH;
                            this.screenHeight = GameStartPoint.HEIGHT;
                            reptiletexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Images/basketball.png"));
                            reptileRegion = new TextureRegion(reptiletexture);
                            this.setVisible(true);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void draw(SpriteBatch batch,float parentAlpha)
                        {
                            super.draw(batch,parentAlpha);


                           batch.draw(reptileRegion, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(),
                                    getOriginY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(),
                                    getScaleY(), getRotation());



                        }

                        public void updateReptile(float x,float y)
                        {
                            int duration = 5;
                             if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
                             {
                                 MoveToAction action = Actions.action(MoveToAction.class);
                                 action.setPosition(x, y);
                                 action.setDuration(duration);
                                 this.addAction(action);
                             }

                        }



                        @Override
                        public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
                            //Gdx.app.log("","reptile is touched.. ") ;
                            updateReptile(x,y);
                            return super.hit(x, y, touchable);

                        }


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw an actor above the tilemap you must call `stage.draw` after rendering tilemap like this:

```java
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    render();
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
}
```

For the collision part you can get the objects that you have created in the `TiledMap` in different classes such as
**EllipseMapObject,     PolygonMapObject,   RectangleMapObject etc.** from where you can extract polylines, polygons etc. and use **Intersector** class to check their bounds.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but this was the first hit when I was googling for the same problem...

If the actor uses some other methods for drawing instead of the batch, the batch should be ended and then restarted again at the end of the method. So in BackgroundTiledMap:

```
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.end();
    render();  // Renders the TiledMap using OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer
    batch.begin();
}
```

See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#drawing for more info.